# ¿Cómo validar y mandar una alerta cuando el servicio back no esta disponible desde Angular?

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, microservices

Tengo la siguiente tabla que se llena al consultar un servicio back en Java a través del método **obtenerLista()**
lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el servicio Java por alguna razon no este disponible, se encuentre down, el front mande una alerta de "Servicio no disponible" al entrar a la pagina

este es mi codigo en el component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Control } from './Control';
import { ControlService } from './control.service';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Estado } from './Estado.ts';
import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';
import { UntypedFormBuilder, UntypedFormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'prueba-angular-material';
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'idControl',
    'cveEstado',
    'comentario',
    'horaInicio',
    'fechaRegistro',
    'botonSave',
  ];
  estadoModel: Estado[] = [];
  control: Control[] = [];
  controlModel: Control = new Control();
  estadoSeleccionado: any;
  idSeleccionado: string = '';
  comentIngresado: string = '';
  horaIngresada: string ='';
  fechaIngresada: any;
  dataModel: any[] = [];
  horaInvalida = true;
  
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;

  constructor(
    private controlService: ControlService,
    private dataAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>
  ) {
    this.dataAdapter.setLocale('es-MX');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obtenerLista();
    this.obtenerListaEstados();
    
  }

  //obtiene la lista del servicio
  dataSource: any;
  private obtenerLista() {
    this.controlService.obtenerLista().subscribe((response) => {
      this.control = response.data;
      console.log("PRUEBA " ,response.data);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.control);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }

  //obtiene la lista de estados para el select
  private obtenerListaEstados() {
    this.controlService.obtenerEstados().subscribe((response) => {
      console.log("PRUEBA  estados" ,response.data);
      this.estadoModel = response.data;
    });
  }

  //obtiene la cve del estado que se selecciona y su id
  cambiarEstado(valor: Event, row: any) {
    this.estadoSeleccionado = valor;
    this.idSeleccionado = row.idControl;

    console.log(' ID SELECC ' + this.idSeleccionado);
    console.log(' ESTADO SELECC ' + this.estadoSeleccionado);
  }

  //obtiene el valor ingresado en el input coment  y el id
  changeValue(e: any, row: any) {
    this.comentIngresado = e.value;
    console.log(' INPUT COMENT  ' + this.comentIngresado);
  }

 //obtiene el valor ingresado en el input hora, y el id
 changeValueHora(e: any, row: any) {
  this.horaIngresada = e.value;
  console.log(' INPUT HORA   ' +this.horaIngresada);
  this.validarHora();
}

validarHora() {
  console.log(' ENTRA A VALIDAR HORA');
  const regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}$");
  this.horaInvalida = !regex.test(this.horaIngresada);
  console.log('HORA '  + this.horaInvalida);
}


  //OBTIENE EL VALOR DE LA FECHA SELECCIONADA
  onDateChange(valor: Event, row: any) {
    this.fechaIngresada = valor;
    console.log('FECHA SELECC  ' + this.fechaIngresada);
  }

  //funcion para darle formato a la fecha internamente
  formatDateToString(date: Date): string {
    if (date) {
      const format = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
      const locale = 'en-US';
      return formatDate(date, format, locale);
    }
    return '';
  }

  deshabilitarOpcion(cveEstado: string): string[] {
    console.log("disabled    ",cveEstado);
    switch (cveEstado) {
      case 'INP':
        return ['FINISHED','PENDING'];
      case 'En Proceso':
        return ['Iniciado'];
      default:
        return [];
    }
  }

  guardar(element: any) {
    if (element.editar) {
      console.log(`Desactivado para ${element.idControl}`);
      element.editar = false;

      if (this.comentIngresado == '') {
        alert('No se han modificado campos');
      } else {
        console.log(' ENTRA ELSE  ');
        this.controlModel.cveEstado = this.estadoSeleccionado;
        this.controlModel.comentario = this.comentIngresado;
        this.controlModel.idControl = this.idSeleccionado;
        this.controlModel.fechaRegistro = this.formatDateToString(
          this.fechaIngresada
        );

        console.log('prueba fecha final  ' + this.controlModel.fechaRegistro);
        this.controlService
          .updateCampo(this.controlModel)
          .subscribe((data) => {
            this.controlModel = data;
            this.comentIngresado = '';
            this.estadoSeleccionado = '';
            this.fechaIngresada = '';

            alert('Agregado correctamente');
          });
      }
    } else {
      console.log(`Activado para ${element.idControl}`);
      element.editar = true;
    }
  }
}
```

service.ts

```
private baseUrl="http://localhost:8080/getLista";
  constructor( private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  obtenerLista():Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Control>(this.baseUrl); 
  }
```

y mi controller en Java

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/getLista"})
public class ControlEController {
    
    
    @Autowired
    private ControlEService controlService;
    
    @GetMapping
    private ResponseEntity<?> listado() throws Exception{
        ResponseEntity<?> list = null;
        try {
            list = controlService.listar();
            //System.out.println("PRUEBA DATOS" +list);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return list;
        
    }
```

serviceImpl

```
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<?> listar() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        List<ControlEntity> list = new ArrayList<ControlEntity>();
        try {
            list = repository.listar();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.put("sucess", false);
            response.put("error", e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        response.put("success", true);
        response.put("data", list);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Actualmente si el servicio esta abajo, marca esto en la consola del navegador, y es lo que quiero controlar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

como puedes revisar tu mismo en la [guía de angular](https://angular.io/guide/http),

cuando HttpClient no puede obtener la respuesta ideal regresa un objeto de error

en este caso en tu service.ts deberás de hacer las siguientes modificaciones:

- encadenar un manejador de errores personalizado
- cuando el código de error sea 0 manejar los problemas de conexión
- cuando el código sea otro manejarlo de otra manera
- usar un mensaje amigable al usuario (que no quiere saber detalles técnicos)

En código se vería algo así:

```
  import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
  import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';



  private baseUrl="http://localhost:8080/getLista";
  constructor( private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  obtenerLista():Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Control>(this.baseUrl).pipe(
      catchError(this.manejaError)
    ); 
  }

private manejaError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (error.status === 0) {
    // Error del lado cliente o problema de red.
    console.error('El servicio back no esta disponible:', error.error);
  } else {
    // El backend responde pero con un codigo de error.
    // Los detalles del error pueden venir en el cuerpo de la respuesta.
    // aquí puedes en vez de imprimirlos en consola mandarlos por correo al equipo de desarrollo
    console.error(
      `Codigo de error del servidor ${error.status}, comparta con soporte tecnico la siguiente informacion de depuracion: `, error.error);
  }
  // Regresar un observable con le mensaje que se le mostrara al usuario
  return throwError(() => new Error('Ya valió... o tal vez no intenta mas tarde.'));
}
```

Comment: Si en el catchError devuelves un throwError va a seguir teniendo un problema porque en su suscripción solo está esperando que todo vaya bien, debería modificarla para manejar el error obtenido también.

Comment: si, puede poner un catch en su controlador para mostrar un alert o algo similar, lo puse así para no mezclar lógicas distintas, ya sabes... responsabilidad única

Comment: Si, si lo entiendo, y la respuesta responde perfectamente a la pregunta. Pero no es muy user-friendly pegar errores en consola sin reflejarlos en la pantalla, pocos usuarios van a tener abierta la consola jeje Simplemente quería aclararlo para que sepa qué curso tomar a continuación para mostrarle el error a los usuarios :)